# MongoDb custom accumulator in group aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use the custom accumulator ($accumulator) in $group for Mongo aggregation pipeline. My records are simple: they have multiple date of uploads and some user posts. There could be multiple posts on a given date of upload.
For e.g. if I have documents like:

```
Date of Upload: 15/08/2020, Post: "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" 
Date of Upload: 15/08/2020, Post: "Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" 
Date of Upload: 14/08/2020, Post: "Cccccccccccccccccc" 
Date of Upload: 12/08/2020, Post: "Ddddddddddddddddd"
```

Then in the result I want to get both "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" and "Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb". Using $first gives me only one document. My objective is to find out all the latest post i.e. posts for a max day in the database from a given date. I tried using following, but it isn't working:

```
{
  _id: null,
  maxDate: {
    $max: '$Date Of Upload'
  },
  docs: {
    $accumulator: {
      init: function(){ return {docs: []}}
      accumulate: function(state, doc,maxDate){
        if (doc."Date Of Upload" == maxDate){
          state.docs.push(doc);
        }
        return state;
      }
      
      accumulateArgs: ['$$ROOT', '$maxDate'],
      finalize: function(state){
        return state.docs
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me fix this? As a workaround, I have pushed all docs from the $group stage to an array, then do $unwind and then $match. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't understand why a simple $max ot $first does not work. Please show us 2-3 sample documents and expected result.

Comment: That only gives me one document. For e.g. if I have documents like:
Date of Upload: 15/08/2020, Post: "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
Date of Upload: 15/08/2020, Post: "Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
Date of Upload: 14/08/2020, Post: "Cccccccccccccccccc"
Date of Upload: 12/08/2020, Post: "Ddddddddddddddddd"

Then in the result I want to get both "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" and "Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb". Using $first gives me only one document

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting additional information as comments

Comment: Thanks. Hope my question is better now.